# Problema no code snippet

Tags: suporte

Bom dia! Não sei se é aqui ou no site mesmo que pergunto, mas tive uma pergunta deletada por estar fora de escopo:
[Cursor sai do final da textbox ao alterar a máscara](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/477432/cursor-sai-do-final-da-textbox-ao-alterar-a-m%c3%a1scara)

Creio que seja pelo code snippet não estar funcionando corretamente, porém não consegui corrigir. A dúvida é: o que está faltando para ele funcionar?

Além disso, a pergunta possui algum outro problema?

Obrigado!

Comment: É aqui mesmo que se faz o questionamento. Já vamos dar uma olhada na sua pergunta.

Comment: O código que foi adicionado para ficar como exemplo minimo na pergunta tinha um informação faltando que éra o `id` do `TelContato` fato que é gerado automaticamente pelo C# mas aqui deve ser colocado na mão.

Comment: Já votei para reabrir. Acho que com a correção do @novic o [mcve] é valido.

Comment: Ah obrigado pessoal, fiquei quebrando a cabeça com isso, não sabia que precisava do id.

Comment: Caro Vitor, a pergunta não foi deletada, a caixa azul acima explica o motivo do fechamento, sem o código apresentado o unico problema aparente era o maxLength do input, graças ao @novic agora o problema ficou claro.... Vou adiantar que o problema é a forma que aplicou o mask, o mask tem eventos proprios conforme a doc https://igorescobar.github.io/-Plugin/docs.html, se a intenção é usar o nono digito essa me parece a solução mais correta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/172054/3635 (que usa o "nativo" do jquery.mask)

Comment: Guilherme, obrigado pelo feedback. Não tinha encontrado essa pergunta, se não nem teria criado o post. Erro meu.

Comment: Fiquei até chateado que já tinha uma solução pronta, tava me entretendo descobrir isso.